# Are the partial derivatives of the real and imaginary part of a holomorphic function always continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm quite confused by my course notes for Complex Analysis. On the one hand, it says that a complex function $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is differentiable at a point $z_0$ iff the corresponding vector-function $F:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ is differentiable and the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied. Now differentiability of a multivariate real function is equivalent to the continuity of partial derivatives, so this would imply for $f(z) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ that $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ have continuous partial derivatives.

On the other hand, the proof that is given for the Cauchy-Goursat theorem is an extremely long, convoluted one, and at the end of it, it mentions that a much more elegant and short proof is possible if one assumes that $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ have continuous partial derivatives (it makes use of Green's theorem). Why is this an 'assumption'? Doesn't it necessarily follow from the assumption of $f$ differentiable in the theorem statement?

Comment: Differentiability of a multivariate real function is *not* equivalent to continuity of the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, differentiability of a multivariate real function is *not* equivalent to the continuity of partial derivatives. For instance, if$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne 0\\0&\text{ if }x=0,\end{cases}$$then $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is dicontinuous there.

However, it is true that the continuity of partial derivatives implies differentiability.

Comment: I see! So continuity of partial derivatives implies differentiability but not the other way around? Also, would continuous differentiability be equivalent to continuity of partial derivatives?

Comment: I think that the usual definition of continuous differentiability is precisely that the partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: The definition given in my book is that the Jacobian is continuous as a function of the partial derivatives, but I guess that's equivalent because continuity of the entries of a matrix guarantees continuity of the matrix, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was really troubling me!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is differentiable at a point $z_{0}$ if and only if the corresponding function $F = Re(f)+Im(f):\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ is differentiable at $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ where $z_{0} = x_{0} + i y_{0}$ and the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied. However, the sufficient condition for differentiabllity theorem only says that if the partial derivatives of $F$ are continuous at $c$ then it is differentiable at $c$, it's not a bidirectional implication as you can find a counterexample in José Carlos answer.

In relation to the Cauchy-Goursat theorem, take into account that the function is holomorphic at $U \setminus \,\{p\,\}$ where p is a point in $U$.